# Updating multi-level object value from dataset value

Tags: javascript

difficult one to explain.

```
var options = {
  container: node,
  pin: {
    size: [50, 50],
    anchor: 0,
    animation: 0
  }
}
```

Let's use the above Object as an example. I want to loop through the dataset from an HTMLElement and update the above values using the dataset values. This removed the need to manually check if the dataset value exists and then replace the value.

What I have got so far:

```
(function() {
  for( const data in node.dataset ) {
    // First remove the 'map' as this isn't required, then split any values with multiple capitals,
    // as these corrospond to multilevel object values. 
    var key = (data.replace("map", "")).split(/(?=[A-Z])/), value = node.dataset[data];

    const findOption = function() {

    };

    // Check that there is a value
    if (value !== null) {
      const opt = null;
      // Find the corresponding default option

    }
  }
}.call(_));
```

Here is the HTML with the dataset attributes, this should help everything make more sense:

```
<div data-map data-map-offset='[10, 10]' data-map-pin-size='[20, 20]'></div>
```

As you can see above the attribute `data-map-pin-size` needs to replace the value within the object, but i'm not sure how to reference that object as usually I would either do `options.pin.size` or `options['pin']['size']`. But due to this loop not knowing how deep it needs to go I can't always rely on this, I need some kind of callback function right? Which is why I started `findOption()` however i'm not too sure where to go from there!

**Edit:**
This is what I have got so far now, however this isn't updating the `options` object, it's just setting the value of `opt`.

```
(function() {
      for( const data in node.dataset ) {
        // First remove the 'map' as this isn't required, then split any values with multiple capitals,
        // as these corrospond to multilevel object values. 
        var key = (data.replace("map", "")).split(/(?=[A-Z])/), value = node.dataset[data];
        // Pin Size
        const findOption = function(val) {
          return options[val.toLowerCase()]; 
        };
        // Check that there is a value
        if (value !== null) {
          var opt = null;
          // Find the corresponding default option
          for (var x = 0; key.length > x; x++) {
            opt = findOption(key[x]);
          }
          opt = value;
        }
      }
      console.log(options);
    }.call(_));
```

Comment: Any chance your `options` object could be formatted like `{ container: ..., pinSize: ..., pinAnchor: ..., pinAnimation: ... }` instead?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I suppose they could, I just wanted to keep related options together. Would it be difficult to do what im attempting?

Comment: Not terribly difficult, but more difficult than it would need to be. The `dataset` property automatically converts kebab-case data-attributes from the HTML into camelCase properties on itself, if you hadn't already noticed, so converting the format of your `options` object would trivialize the transfer of properties.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts okay I will do that thanks. Just wanted the code to look neater and more organised but it's only going to be modified by me anyway and minified when done so I suppose it's not that big of a deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert your `options` to this format:

```
var options = {
  container: node,
  pinSize: [50, 50],
  pinAnchor: 0,
  pinAnimation: 0
}
```

your implementation would be able to be simplified to this:

```
for (const key in node.dataset) {
  const opt = key.replace(/^map(.)/, (match, c) => c.toLowerCase())
  options[opt] = JSON.parse(node.dataset[key])
}
```

assuming you intend to use JSON-compliant values in your HTML `data-` attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Here I added a `recursive function` to set the value by finding the specific key on the `options` object. You can see that for any length of `data set` attribute the values are getting set properly.

This works with any kind of `options object` format *dynamically*.

**I added an extra sample as well to demonstrate it**.

```js
(function() {


  //A function to set the value on a nested object by
  //recursively finding the key
  function setValue(object, key, value) {
    var value;
    Object.keys(object).some(function(k) {
      if (k === key) {
        object[k] = value;
      }
      if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object') {
        setValue(object[k], key, value);
      }
    });
  }

  node = document.getElementById("elem");

  var options = {
    container: node,
    pin: {
      size: [50, 50],
      anchor: 0,
      animation: 0,
      value: {
        xy: [1, 1]
      }
    }
  }

  for (const data in node.dataset) {
    // First remove the 'map' as this isn't required, then split any values with multiple capitals,
    // as these corrospond to multilevel object values. 
    var keys = (data.replace("map", "")).split(/(?=[A-Z])/),
      value = node.dataset[data];

    var findOption = function() {
      keys.forEach(function(key, index) {
        if (index == keys.length - 1) {
          setValue(options, key.toLowerCase(), value);
        }
      })
    }();


    // Check that there is a value
    if (value !== null) {
      const opt = null;
      // Find the corresponding default option
    }
  }

  console.log(options);

}.call());
```

```html
<div data-map data-map-offset='[10, 10]' data-map-pin-size='[20, 20]' data-map-pin-value-xy='[0, 5]' id="elem"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will save this as a reference for the future, gone with Patrick's idea this time however.